# What is the purpose of `Object(target)` in the `Object.assign()` polyfill

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, ecmascript-6, polyfills

In the [MDN page forObject.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) the example polyfill first wraps all sources and the target parameters in `Object()` before iterating over the properties. 
(i.e. `Object(target)`, `Object(source1)`, `Object(source2)`...).

The text also mentions that the additional properties are added directly to the target before returning the target. However, wrapping the target in `Object()` results in an object that is different than simply augmenting properties. (i.e. `Object(target).newProp !== target.newProp`).

All the examples given have objects as parameters to `Object.assign()`. The use-case for non-object source or target parameters is therefore not clear.

**A)** What is the purpose of wrapping parameters in `Object()`? (I am under the impression that `Object.keys(x)` is the same as `Object.keys(Object(x))`).

**B)** What are possible use cases for using `Object.assign()` with non-objects, is any? (for example something like: `Object.assign(1, 'b', [3], true, function(){})` )

Comment: `Object(target)` casts the target into an object. For example: `Object("1234")` casts this to `[object String] {0: "1", 1: "2", 2: "3", 3: "4", length: 4}`

Comment: Usually best to read the specification in conjunction with the polyfill, as they often try to replicate the behaviour. You can see from the [*ed. 6 draft*](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-object.assign), that each argument is passed to *ToObject*. Since native script can't access internal methods, calling `Object(target)` and `Object(source)` is an approximation (though not precisely the same, especially for *null* and *undefined*).

Comment: @Mouser. I understand what Object() does. What I don't understand is why you would ever do something like Object.assign([], 'a', 3, function(){})

Comment: When you have an object with properties that you need to transfer to another object: When you need to alter properties of object `A` but you want to let `A` intact, you could copy the properties to `B` and change them, much like you would use `slice` to copy part of an array.

Comment: @RobG. Thanks for the link to the spec. Looking at it, it is meant to copy the sources own enumerable properties. Isn't this already done by Object.keys()? I get the same outcome with Object.keys(x) and Object.keys(Object(x)) weather x is a string, number or function. So I am missing the purpose of the wrapping and the purpose of using Object.assign on non-objects.

Comment: @Mouser. I understand how to transfer properties between objects. I do this frequently. What I don't get is why the polyfill uses `Object.keys(Object(x))` instead of simply `Object.keys(x)`. What I am missing?

Comment: Thanks to a comment from Mouser I found the source of my 1st question. Turns out that in **ES5** `Object.keys()` is meant to fail on non-object (TypeError) while in **ES6**  a non-object argument will be coerced to an object. So `Object.keys(x)` in **ES6** is the same as `Object.keys(Object(x))` in **ES5**. The latest Firefox and Chrome have already implemented this ES6 behavior while Explorer 10 is following ES5. This is the source of my confusion since I was relying on Chrome and Firefox to test my hypothesis.

Answer (score 2):

Let's break it down:

> Test if the object exists, if not make it:

```
if (!Object.assign) {
```

> Make the method via `Object.defineProperty` and add it to `Object`

```
    Object.defineProperty(Object, 'assign', {
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: true,
    writable: true,
```

> Here the actual function gets set. One needs to supply a target and one source minimum.

```
    value: function(target, firstSource) {
      'use strict';
```

> If the target is not defined throw an error.

```
      if (target === undefined || target === null) {
        throw new TypeError('Cannot convert first argument to object');
      }
```

> Cast the target to Object format. (E.g. String `1234` to `[object String]{0: "1", 1: "2", 2: "3", 3: "4", length: 4}`.

```
      var to = Object(target);
```

> Now loop through all sources using the arguments object of the function. Start with 1, since 0 is the target.

```
      for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var nextSource = arguments[i]; //store the argument in a variable.
        if (nextSource === undefined || nextSource === null) {
          continue; //if the source is undefined continue. 
        }
```

> Then we need all (not only the exposed) the enumerable properties from the source object, use `Object.keys` in combination with `Object(source)`.

```
        var keysArray = Object.keys(Object(nextSource));
```

> Iterate over the keys:

```
        for (var nextIndex = 0, len = keysArray.length; nextIndex < len; nextIndex++) {
          var nextKey = keysArray[nextIndex]; //select the key from the index.
```

> `getOwnPropertyDescriptor` gives us information about the property in the form of an object.

```
          var desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(nextSource, nextKey);
```

> If the property is not undefined and is enumerable then set this property as a property to `to`.

```
          if (desc !== undefined && desc.enumerable) {
            to[nextKey] = nextSource[nextKey];
          }
        }
      }
      return to;
    }
  });
}
```

Finally return `to` with the newly added (cloned) properties.

Comment: Nice but the reason that `var to = Object(target);` is done is not so that "the code can enumerate over the properties", but rather if the target was not an object (for example `1` ) one couldn't assign properties to it. There is no loop over the properties of the target to support that claim.

Comment: True, it never enumerates them. It only converts to an object.

Comment: Sorry I still don't get it. The bit in the polyfill that I don't understand (hence the question) is the step "Cast the target to Object format". I get the same result with `Object.keys('abcd')` as in `Object.keys(Object('abcd'))` so I am guessing that the wrapping is for other uses that I can't yet think of.

Comment: @Dan D. Then, in light of the question, why also wrap the sources and why would you ever use Object assign on non-objects? I've tried Object.keys() with and without the Object() conversion and always get the same outcomes.

Comment: Well `Object.keys('abcd')` fails in IE11 with `Object.keys: argument is not an object` however `Object.keys(Object('abcd'))` won't fail.

Comment: @Mouser. Thanks. this is a good lead since I was only toying around the Chrome console. I just checked and Object.key('abc') works in Firefox too.  It is possible that the answer lies in the Object.keys() specification and the different implementation between browsers.